# lost information when not all values have "value labels" in sjmisc sjPlot

Tags: r, label, sjplot

In sjmisc / sjPlot r packages I've got a variable in which not all the values have 'value labels'. See example:

```
library ("sjmisc")
library ("sjPlot")
agreement <- sample (1:5, 40, replace = TRUE)
agreement <- set_labels(agreement, c(`1` = "Full agree",`5` = "Full  disagree"))
```

When I ask for a frequency table some information is lost:

```
sjt.frq(agreement)
```

This is what you get:

```
data
value       N   raw %   valid %     cumulative %
Full agree  4   10.00   10.00       10.00
2           7   17.50   17.50       27.50
missings    0   0.00        
total N=11 · valid N=11 · x̄=3.40 · σ=1.22
```

Any help? Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is currently a shortcoming with non-complete labelled vectors. You can use following workaround with `to_factor`:

```
sjt.frq(to_factor(agreement, add.non.labelled = T))
```

or, for a console output:

```
frq(as_labelled(agreement))
```

I've [added](https://github.com/sjPlot/devel/issues/69) this issue, so I can remove this bug in a forthcoming update...

Edit: The bug is fixed in the current [GitHub-build](https://github.com/sjPlot/devel), which - however - requires the latest [sjmisc-build](https://github.com/sjPlot/sjmisc) to run. Updated for CRAN to be submitted the next 2-3 weeks.